# How to access values in JSON object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, response

Is `status` a useable JSON object?

How can I access the values of `action_success` and `newIndex` on `status`?

Server:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles()
{
    // save file..
    return Json(new { action_success = "true", newIndex = 2 });
}
```

Client:

```
complete: function (e, data) {
    var status = e.currentTarget.response;
    // From FireBug: status is "{"action_success":"true","newIndex":2}"
    // Including the first and last double-quote.

    // I want to do something like:
    // status.action_success and status.newIndex but I can't!    
}
```

**EDIT:**
Simple solution:

```
var statusParsed = JSON.parse(status);
var success = statusParsed.action_success;
var index = statusParsed.newIndex;
```

Comment: hmm I need JSON.parse()?

Comment: I didn't knew about JSON.parse() when I wrote the question. I was something I found after. I'm trying it now, don't hate me.

Comment: Which AJAX API is used in JavaScript, and how is it initiated? (jQuery will normally default to auto-parsing JSON.)

Comment: I can access action_success and newIndex by "." from status now, after adding this line: `                    var statusParsed = JSON.parse(status);
`

Comment: @user2864740 I don't know what you mean. I can tell you my jQuery version and the version of wijmo if it's that? It's a wijUpload function you see on my client side.

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(data);` inside the complete function ?

Comment: data contains alot of things. It's not possible to say them all.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use direct JsonResult and should work

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFiles()
{
// save file..
return Json(new { action_success = "true", newIndex = 2 });
}
```

and on client side if you are using $.ajax() then set datatype as json